# Deserialize JSON with inconsistent property

Tags: c#, json.net

I want deserialize `JSON` into an object in `C#`

But one of the properties can be

`List<double>` or `List<List<double>>` or `List<List<List<double>>>>`

And it depends on another property

How can this be done?

```
[JsonProperty("type")]
public string Type { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("coordinates")]
public List<double> Coordinates { get; set; }
```

How can I add that if the `Type = X -> Coordinates = List<double>`

And if `Type = Y -> Coordinates = List<List<double>>` and so on

Comment: You could use a custom Serializer/Deserializer to handle the different cases. I would probably also build different classes for your different types

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could help me with some small example

Answer (score -1):

I was able to compile quick piece of code based on your question. So you know, I used Newtonsoft to write it as I already had a sample available that I needed to modify a little for your usage.

```
//Classes
class TypeBase
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

class TypeX : TypeBase
{

    [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
    public List<double> Coordinates { get; set; }

}

class TypeY : TypeBase
{

    [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
    public List<List<double>> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the Custom JsonConverter that you'll need

```
public class DataObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(TypeX) || objectType == typeof(TypeY) || objectType == typeof(TypeBase);
    }
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var dataType = obj.Property("type", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if ("X".Equals(dataType?.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return obj?.ToObject<TypeX>();
        }
        if ("Y".Equals(dataType?.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return obj?.ToObject<TypeY>();
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the code on how to use the whole thing:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DataObjectConverter());
var typeX = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeBase>(t, serializerSettings);
var typeY = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeBase>(ty, serializerSettings);

if (typeX.Type == "X")
{
    var typeXObj = (TypeX)typeX;
    Console.WriteLine(typeXObj.Coordinates.Count);
}
//etc.
```